# ui-router: validate and alter url params during state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have three different parent states that each have a set of url parameters.
They share some of the same params, but not always, for example:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('state1',{
      url : 'state1',
      params : {
        start : {value: null, squash : true, dynamic : true},
        end : {value: null, squash : true, dynamic : true},
        tz : {value: 'Eastern', squash: true, dynamic : true}
      }
   }
   .state('state2',{
      url : 'state2',
      params : {
        end : {value: null, squash : true, dynamic : true}
      }
   }
   .state('state3',{
      url : 'state3',
      params : {
        start : {value: null, squash : true, dynamic : true},
        end : {value: null, squash : true, dynamic : true},
        tz : {value: 'Eastern', squash: true, dynamic : true},
        period : {value: 'Quarter', squash: true, dynamic : true}
      }
   }
```

I'm trying to set up the ability to do some validation when switching states.

For example, let's say the user is in `state1` with a url of `state1?start=20160101&end=20160131` and clicks a link to `state2`, but in `state2`, there is only one date (`end`), and it only takes the year (eg. 2016), so I need to load `state2` but change the `end` param to have a different value.

I've tried using the following:

```
angular.module('myApp',[ui.router,ui.router.default])
    .run(['$transitions','$state',runFunction]);

    function runFunction($transitions,$state){
        var match = {
            to: 'state2',
            from: 'state1'
        };

        $transitions.onBefore(match,function($transitions$,$state){
            var fromParams = $transition$.params('from');
            var toParams = $transition$.params('to');
            if(fromParams.end){
                toParams.end = fromParams.end.substr(0,4);
            }else{
                toParams.end = '2016';
            }
            return $state.transitionTo($transition$.to().name, toParams);
        }
    }
```

My issue with this is that I run into an infinite loop.

I'd like the ability to perform any number of param validations, and make param changes if need be.  Am I going about this is the right way?

Using angular ui-router 1.0.0-alpha.3

Thanks!!

Comment: use params as null then you can dinamicly set params in $state.go $state.go('state2', {param1: value1})

Comment: You can add an extra parameter `validated` after the validation, and don't call `$state.transitionTo` if it's already there.

Comment: @ZeRubeus that works ok except for the `onBefore` keeps recognizing a state change, which turns into an infinite loop

Comment: @VictorSergienko My issue is that I _do_ want to change the state, but with updated params.  Once I run a `$state.go` or `$state.transitionTo`, the onBefore is matched again, and the whole process runs again. Perhaps I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this using simple logic to not allow infinite loop:

```
angular.module('myApp',[ui.router,ui.router.default])
.run(['$transitions','$state',runFunction]);

// variables outside the run function
var params = {};
var transition_count = 0;

function runFunction($transitions,$state){
    var match = {
        to: 'state2',
        from: 'state1'
    };

    $transitions.onBefore(match,function($transitions$,$state,$q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var target = true;
        var origParams = $transition$.params('from');
        var first_loop =  transition_count === 0 ? true: false;
        if(first_loop){
            params = $transition$.params('from');
        }

        if(origParams .end){
            params .end = origParams .end.substr(0,4);
            target = false;
        }else{
            params .end = '2016';
            target = false;
        }

        if(!target){
            $state.go($transition$.to().name, params);
            transtion_count++;
        }else{
            params = {};   // reset the params to empty object
            transition_count = 0; // reset transition_count
        }
        deferred.resolve(target);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```