# How to change params value during transition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

During transition I would like to be able to change params values. In documentation I found a method to access target states params [using `params('to')` method](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#params). In my code it looks like this

```
$transitions.onStart({ from: 'state3', to: 'state1' }, function ($transition$) {
    var params = $transition$.params('to');
    if(someCondition){
        params.success = true;
    }
    $transition$.params['to'] = params;
});
```

My `state1` definition looks like this

```
$stateProvider
    .state('state1', {
        url: '/',
        params: {
            success: false,
        },
        ...
```

However, when I perform transition, with code listed above, my `success` parameter has always default value (which is `false`).

Question is - is it possible to change values of parameters during transition?

Background: I have two buttons, which allows transition from `state3` to `state1`. One I can control from my `$scope`, but the other is breadcrumb link outside of `$scope`. I figured I could use this `$transitions` hook, to check some conditions and set `success` to appropriate value.

I've stumbled across answer [suggesting performing whole new $state.go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736976/ui-router-validate-and-alter-url-params-during-state-change) with new params, but I find it a little bit messy and hacky. I have a feeling, that it can be achieved in simpler and cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't manage to change those values during particular transition, but when I changed `onStart` to `onSuccess` I was simply able to make whole new transition with my new parameters

```
$transitions.onSuccess({ from: 'state3', to: 'state1' }, function ($transition$) {
    var fromParams = $transition$.params('from');
    if (someCondition) {
        return $state.transitionTo('state1');
    }
    return $state.transitionTo('state1', { success: true }, { notify: false });
});
```

Changing to `onSuccess` prevented infinite transition loop, which was happening when I was calling new transition in `onStart` event.